# Getting Sharepoint selected list item by using Client Side Object Model (CSOM)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

Can anybody please help me by suggesting good site or sample code for Getting Sharepoint selected list item by using Client Side Object Model (CSOM) in sharepoint 2010. I need to print these selected items by using CSOM. Please help me for this. Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 6):

[SP.ListOperation.Selection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408826%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Provides methods for selecting lists or list items, in particular [SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Gets the list items being selected

Example 1: Get selected items

```
function getSelectedItems()
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    return selectedItems;
}
```

> Note: Method SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems returns the key/value collection > that contains the list
>   items being selected (not SP.ListItem collection!)

Example 2. Get selected SP.ListItem collection

```
function getSelectedItems(OnSuccess,OnError)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //selected list Id
    var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //selected Items Ids

    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    var listItems = [];
    for (idx in selectedItemIds)
    {
        var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
        listItems.push(item);
        context.load(item);
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(
       function() {
          OnSuccess(listItems);       
       },
       OnError
    ); 

}

//Usage
getSelectedItems(function(items){
    for (var i =0 ; i < items.length;i++)
    {
       console.log(items[i].get_item('Title'));  
    }  
},function(sender,args){
    console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, thank you for your answer. But, how should I return true or false if I want to check whether the specific value of **'Title'** equals to a certain value? I would like to use this method to enable or disable the ribbon button, so the best way is returning true or false. Do you have any idea about this?